# Filter a dataframe using values from a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, lines-of-code

I have a dataframe DF, I want to filter rows based on values on a dictionary

```
fruits = {'BN':'Banana', 'LM': 'Lemon', 'AP':'Apple', 'MG': 'Mango'}
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
df = df.loc[df['FruitName'] in fruits.values()]
```

I get the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.isin()`:

```py
df = df[df["FruitName"].isin(fruits.values())]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  FruitName
0     Lemon
2     Mango
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
    FruitName
0       Lemon
1  Grapefruit
2       Mango
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked
I will mark it as solved